# Can't get 'make' to work on OSX; have to use 'make -f <file>'

Tags: macos, makefile

I'm trying to get started building my own make files, but am having some trouble getting my Mac to use them.  I can issue the command `make -f makefile.txt` and it compiles my project fine; however, just using `make` produces the following:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
all:
        g++ main.c -o hello
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're naming the Makefile inappropriately. It should be named simply `Makefile` (with no extension), not `makefile.txt`.

Comment: And this applies across all platforms; it is not peculiar to Mac in the slightest.  The `make` program expects to find either `makefile` or `Makefile` (which are essentially the same on Mac OS X as it is a case-insensitive file system).

Comment: For historical reasons, the GNU implementation of `make` will actually also look for a `GNUmakefile`. But that's kind of a footnote.